# How to make password reset link feature limited only to non-third party auth service provider created accounts

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have this problem encountered in the flutter and firebase password reset link. My goal to limit only the said feature for those users who created their account locally(email and password) and not using other supported auth service providers (ie. google, facebook, twitter). I want to do this because I am encountering an issue that even accounts registered like for example, via google auth provider can request a password reset link - which is I think a problem since the said account doesn't have a password registered.

I thought checking the **providerId** will solve such an issue, but unfortunately, it will not work since the password reset feature only available in the login form which is normally, no currentUser is available since no logged-in user (currentUser == null) and will throw an error if applied.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

This is my current code for the password reset;

```
  Future<String> sendPasswordResetLink(String userEmail, String errMessage) async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: userEmail);
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      errMessage = 'An error occurred while processing the request. Please check and try again.';
      switch(error.code) {
        case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
          errMessage = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
          errMessage = 'Email address does not exist.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
          errMessage = 'The account has been disabled due to unusual activity.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
          errMessage = 'Too many sign in request. Please try again later.';
          break;
        case 'ERROR_NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED':
          errMessage = 'Cannot process the request. Please check your internet connection and try again.';
          break;
        default:
          errMessage = 'An error occurred while processing the request. Please try again later.';
      }
      if(error.message != null) {
        Future.error(errMessage);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      print(error.toString());
    }
    return errMessage;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to store the emails of the users which created account locally to the Firebase, then you can simply check during password reset if it exists in Firebase or not and act accordingly.